# Top.gg voting Webhooks

Tags: javascript, express, sdk, discord.js, webhooks

I am trying to get my discord bot to console.log vote information when somebody votes for my bot in top.gg. The following code is referencing the example from the official [@top-gg/sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@top-gg/sdk)

```js
var path = require('path');
const { webhookPW } = require(path.resolve(path.normalize("./config.json")));

const init = async() =>
{
    console.log('[EXPRESS] STARTING SERVER')
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const Topgg = require('@top-gg/sdk')
    const webhook = new Topgg.Webhook(webhookPW) // add your top.gg webhook authorization (not bot token)
    
    app.post('/dblwebhook', webhook.middleware(), (req, res) => {
        // req.vote is your vote object e.g
        console.log(req.vote)
    }) // attach the middleware
    
    app.listen(25569, () => console.log('SERVER READY'))
}
    module.exports.init = init
```

On the webhooks page of my bot, I have inputted this information:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9YU.png
The first censor is my VPS' ipv4 (Vultr VPS) and the second is the "webhookPW" that I used in my config.json.

When I press "Test", it states "Webhook tested! This may take a few seconds", but I get nothing in my console on my VPS. I have tried using `sudo ufw allow http` and `sudo ufw allow 25569`, causing `sudo ufw status` to display:

```sh
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
25569                      ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25569 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Edit:

`nc -l 25569` returns `nc: Address already in use` when the bot is running, and nothing when it is not.

Comment: Are you actually recieving a request from top.gg? It could be an issue with your Node app. Try running `nc -l 25569` and see if you get anything printed to the console.

Comment: @theLMGN i got `nc: Address already in use` printed in the console.

Comment: ^this is while my app is running

Comment: This is because only one app can listen on a port at once. Try quitting your node app and then trying the nc command again.

Comment: @theLMGN with the app closed, it is seemingly idle and hangs infinitely (so far)

Comment: If when you click test on the website, nothing comes through, that means that something is blocking it. Try temporarily disabling the firewall, and then if that does not work, contact your hosting provider.

Comment: @theLMGN Thank you very much for your help! it worked.